# NSDateFormatter including redundant "PM" in stringFromDate: on iOS 7.0.6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am facing a bug (?) with NSDateFormatter. First of all, here's a method I use to get the current `NSDate` as `NSString` (converted in a not-so-easy-to-read format because it's sent to a web service) :

```
+ (NSString *) nowToUTCDate {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];

    return [df_utc stringFromDate:now];
}
```

On iOS <= 7.0.4, the result gave me : `20140307203040` (even though I use the 12h format).

On my iPhone (iOS 7.0.6), the result is : `20140307083346 PM` (only if I use the 12h format).
Boom, a " PM" appears ! Why ? I am using the `HH`string to explicitly ask for a 24h format (as said [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)).

As a workaround, I wrote this solution :

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[df_utc setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
```

Is that a bug that was introduced by Apple to the last version of iOS or am I misunderstanding something ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a "feature".  And it's not new.  It's just that the two devices you're testing on are not set up the same.  You can get this symptom when you have a 12-hour locale (eg US) device set to 24-hour mode or a 24-hour locale (eg Europe) device set to 12-hour mode.  Apple swears up and down that it's "by design".

Comment: Thank you Hot Lips for your answer. But, how can we explain that it worked before and the "PM" appears after the update ? Thanx for the link, I didn't see it before... You solved my problem!

Comment: Like I said, it depends on how the specific device is configured (in the device Setup) -- whether locale and 12/24 mode are consistent or in conflict.